# Save data from DataGridView in C# with WinForms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I've two DataGridView one very simple and one more complex with different column types.
My idea was to store store the data to XML and also load from the files at restart.
For the simple one it's no problem (dgvAccounts is the DataGridView):

```
   DataTable dtusers = new DataTable("Users");
   DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("ID");
   DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Key");
   dtUsers.Columns.Add(col1);
   dtUsers.Columns.Add(col2);
   if (File.Exists("user.xml"))
         dtUsers.ReadXml("user.xml");
   dgvAccounts.DataSource = dtUsers;     
   ....
   dtUsers.WriteXml("user.xml");
```

But on the other DataGridView the DataTable I like to get from the DataSource is ever null (dgvActions is the DataGridView):

```
   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvcolA5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcolA6 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   dgvActions.Columns.Add(dgvcolA5);
   dgvActions.Columns.Add(dgvcolA6);
   DataTable dtActions = (DataTable)dgvActions.DataSource;
   dtActions.WriteXML("actions.xml");
```

I'd also tried to create a DataTable in advance and add it as dgvActions.DataSource but the result is ever the same.

So please can somebody help me to create a DataTable for the DataGridView or suggest any other way to store and load the data?

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up the datatable first and then setting it as the datasource like you do in the first example(then you wont get the null datatable from the datasource):

```
   DataTable dtActions = new DataTable();
   //Set DataTable columns here
   dtActions.WriteXML("actions.xml");
   dgvActions.DataSource = dtActions;
```

Comment: I tried this too but in case I add columns direct to the DGV it has no effect. Also I tried to add exact the same olumn names to the DT - no effect the DataTable is ever empty if I bind it in before editing or try to get it before I try to save.

Comment: Can you set the DGV `AutoGenerateColumns` property to true? Then you would only need to create the columns on the `DataTable` and it should carry over to the DGV when you set the `DataSource`

Comment: If I set it to true there're no chances. Only if I do so and add columns to the DataTable - in this case I've the DGV Columns next to the DT Columns.